# Will my app be rejected if it requires ios5?

Tags: iphone

In my iphone app, I used some API new in iOS 5. Since I don't have code to check iOS version and provide fallback for old iOS versions, this app is obviously not going to run on any iOS older than 5.0.

Will the app be rejected because of this? Or can I specify that my app requires iOS 5 or later, upon submission to app store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should specify your minimum OS version in your Info.plist. To set it in Xcode, click on your project, select the 'Summary' tab and put 5.0 in the 'Deployment Target' field.

If you were to upload an app with a deployment target of 4.0, and your app were to crash on 4.0 due to attempting to use unimplemented API then that would be grounds for rejection.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure. I do have development target set to 5.0, so that should be fine, right? I actually do not want to support old iOS versions since I do not have device to test.

Comment: Yep, that should be fine. Apple will ensure it isn't loadable onto any iOS 4 or earlier devices and won't expect your app to work if it somehow were loaded.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you follow the other apple guidelines (like your app doesnt use undocumented api, is not overly simplistic, etc etc) and you specify in the plist all the details, Set that its only ios5 compatible. it wont be rejected.